# pasar json a clase y luego guardar informacion a base de datos

Tags: c#, json

Buen día tengo que realizar lo siguiente tengo un json en el cual debo recorrerlo y cada dato encontrado lo debe pasar a una clase, por ejemplo tengo este json

```
     {
       "nombre":"Jonh Doe",
       "profesion":"Programador",
       "edad":25,
       "lenguajes":["PHP","Javascript","Dart"],
       "disponibilidadParaViajar":true,
       "rangoProfesional": {
       "aniosDeExperiencia": 12,
       "nivel": "Senior"
    }
  }
```

y esta seria la clase de mi json

```
public class RangoProfesional
{
     public int aniosDeExperiencia { get; set; }
     public string nivel { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
     public string nombre { get; set; }
     public string profesion { get; set; }
     public int edad { get; set; }
     public List<string> lenguajes { get; set; }
     public bool disponibilidadParaViajar { get; set; }
     public RangoProfesional rangoProfesional { get; set; }
}
```

y cuando los datos del json pase a esta clase los debe de mandar a una base de datos. pero no tengo la minima idea de como realizarlo ya que soy nuevo en esto, alguna idea o sugerencia de como iniciar cabe recalcar que me lo piden en C#

Comment: el archivo json, como pensas leerlo? viene como parametro de un controlador? o lo lees de un archivo??

Comment: debo crear un procedimiento que me permita recorrer completamente el json pero si no tengo idea de como empezar a realizarlo

Comment: tu json seria una coleccion de varios objetos de tipo Root?? seria como una lista??

Comment: mi json seria asi como esta en la pregunta lo acabo de editar, sorry no me habia percatado que estaba mal redactado

Comment: tienes 2 preguntas en una, para resolver el mapeo del json a objetos puedes utilizar el Newtonsoft.Json y para conectar a la base de datos tienes varias opciones, usando ORMs como EntityFramework o Dapper, o Conectando directamente y escribiendo el Sql a mano, que version de .Net utilizarias?

Comment: 2019 seria. la conexion sera directamente dentro de un servicio no lleva entityFramework, alguna guia o pagina donde me pueda basar para hacer eso

Answer (score 0):

Para la deserializacion del json puedes utilizar la libreria Newtonsoft.Json
por ejemplo un metodo que reciba tu Json en el parametro como un string

Necesitas incluir el using correspondiente:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

El metodo para deserializar (convertir el Json a un Objeto) quedaria asi:

```
public Root ConvertirJson(string json)
{
    Root deserializedRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

    return deserializedRoot;
}
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Luego para enviar esto a la base de datos directamente existen varios caminos

Aqui tienes un ejemplo usando OleDB sin usar EntityFramework como comentaste

http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/tutorial-asp-net-acceso-a-datos-consultar-y-guardar-informacion-desde-webforms/

Este Ejemplo tambien es interesante sobre todo en mostrar la conexion y el envio del comando SQL

https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%23/guardar-cualquier-archivo-en-la-base-de-datos-simplemente-convertirlo-una-matriz-de-bytes/968216897/